# How to load data from UNIX to snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created `CSV` files into `UNIX` server using Informatica resides in. I want to load those `CSV` files directly from `UNIX` box to snowflake using `snowsql`, can someone help me how to do that?

Comment: the PUT command is the normal way to load files into stages https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/put.html

Comment: If Snowsql installed into unix server use put command and push the file into snowflake internal stage then execute the copy command

Answer (score 0):

1. Log into SnowSQL:
   https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/getting-started-tutorial-log-in.html
2. Create a Database, Table and Virtual Warehouse, if not done so already:
   https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/getting-started-tutorial-create-objects.html
3. Stage the CSV files, using `PUT`:
   https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/getting-started-tutorial-stage-data-files.html
4. Copy the files into the target table using `COPY INTO`:
   https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/getting-started-tutorial-copy-into.html